# How to base an iframe source on the value of two dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently visualizing covid-19 based data and presenting it on a website. The visualizations are embedded via an iframe. Currently the website has one dropdown, where the user can select between visualizing the amount of cases or the amount of deaths. This is how I did that:

```
<select class="form-select form-control-lg input-sm" aria-label="Default select example" 

name="options" onchange="document.getElementById('youriframe').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="{% static 'europakartefaelle.html' %}">Europakarte Fälle</option>
<option value="{% static 'europakartetode.html' %}">Europakarte Tode </option>
</select>
</div>
<iframe id = "youriframe" src = "{% static 'europakartefaelle.html' %}" width="100%" height="700" allow="fullscreen" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

What I want to do now is give the user another dropdown, where he can change the way the visualization looks. Currently, all visualizations are done with a choroplethmap, but I also want to display the visualization with a bubble map. I'm not really sure how I should do this, so every help is greatly appreciated!